# Passing extra parameters to route handlers in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm relatively new to Express, and I'm looking for a way to make routes more reusable. In my app, I will have quite a few routes that can be passed to a generic handler, but will have different templates.

Example:

```
app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
    res.render('about.html');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home.html');
});
```

While this example is contrite, I have 30+ such routes. What I would like to be able to do is something like this:

```
app.get('/about', generic.render('about.html'));
```

or otherwise somehow pass the template name to the function that returns `res.render` Is this possible in Express? All of my attempts to work around this result in variables being undefined.

I would prefer to not do something like this, tightly coupling my route parameters and template names:

```
app.get('/:template', function(req, res) {
    res.render(req.params.template + '.html');
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could just make a a simple middleware that does this for you. Example:

```
function simpleRender(file, opts) {
  opts || (opts = {});
  return function(req, res) {
    res.render(file, opts);
  };
}
```

Then just use it like:

```
app.get('/about', simpleRender('about.html'));

app.get('/', simpleRender('home.html'));
```

Comment: That works perfectly. I hadn't thought of returning a generic function in that manner. I'll accept your answer as soon as the site will let me. Many thanks!

Comment: One thing I'm not quite understanding is how the variables `req` and `res` eventually make their way to the inner function that is returned. Could you offer an quick explanation?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but is it such that our function is called first, setting `template` and `opts` into scope, then the inner function is returned back to `app.get()`, where `req` and `res` are passed in, and now that the template variable is in scope, it can be passed to `res.render()` ?

Comment: `simpleRender()` returns a function which is used as the value for the route handler. The `req` and `res` are just parameters that Express passes in, the same way as if you use a literal inline function for your route handler. You are right about how it works.

Comment: Super. I always want to understand why things work instead of blindly cargo-culting code.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do it:

```
const handler = (req, res, template) => {
  res.render(template)
}

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  handler(req, res, 'about.html')
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a best practice for me

```
app.get('/:template',(req, res, next) => {
    res.locals = `${template}.html`;
    next();
  },
  renderMethod
);

function renderMethod(req, res){
  res.render(res.locals)
}
```